# Data type that only stores hour and minute in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

Is there any data type in MSSQL that allows me to store only the hour and minutes of a time value?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because while the OP didn't know the answer this is not a question that will help anybody else in the future.

Comment: @SeanLange Questions that you don't think are useful should be downvoted, not close voted. Questions should be close voted when they are off-topic. See [help] for more information.

Comment: @SeanLange is incorrect. I just googled for this, and this post, and answer, helped me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly.

The closest what you can get is `time(0)`:

```
Specified scale | Result (precision, scale)
---------------------------------------------
time(0)         | (8,0)
```

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> **Character length:** 8 positions minimum (hh:mm:ss) to 16 maximum (hh:mm:ss.nnnnnnn). [...]

If you realy only need the Hour and minute part, you could also have two `tinyint` columns.

If your question is just about the display, then use `ToString("HH:mm")` on `DateTime`. If you only store the time, you get a `TimeSpan` in .net, hence I create a new DateTime instance in this example:

```
var dateTime = new DateTime(timeSpan.Ticks);
var formattedString = dateTime.ToString("HH:mm");
```